# Pass a JSON request body using apex_web_service

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

May I ask if there is a way to pass a JSON request body using apex_web_service.make_rest_request?

The user we are using doesn't have privilege to use UTL_HTTP it returns "PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_HTTP' must be declared" and I cannot do not have permission to change the privilege since I'm not an admin.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, that is what the **p_body** parameter is for. Have a look into the API documentation of APEX_WEB_SERVICE.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.1/aeapi/MAKE_REST_REQUEST-Function.html#GUID-C77BB45A-8968-470C-8243-BADB63743DE9

Answer (score 0):

You can build your json from for example page items in APEX:

```
declare
    l_response clob;
    l_request_body clob;
    l_obj JSON_OBJECT_T := JSON_OBJECT_T();
begin

    l_obj.put('name', :P1_NAME);
    l_obj.put('age', :P1_AGE);
    


    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).name := 'Content-type'; 
    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).value := 'application/json';
        
    l_response := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
        p_url => 'some_service_url'
        , p_http_method => 'PUT'
        , p_body => l_obj
        );
            
    if apex_web_service.g_status_code != 200 then
        raise_application_error(-20001,'Error: Request failed');
    end if;

end;
```